# How to access Spotfire expression values using IronPython script

Tags: ironpython, tibco, spotfire

I'm trying to get the results of expressions in Spotfire 7, i.e., the same values that are shown in visualisations, using an IronPython script.

Consider the following data:

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id |    date    | value |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 | 2016-01-01 |     5 |
|  2 | 2016-01-21 |     6 |
|  3 | 2016-02-01 |     4 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

We could create a scatter plot with `<BinByDateTime([date],'Year.Month',1)>` on the X and `Avg([value])` on the Y axis, showing `5.5` for `2016-Jan` and `4` for `2016-Feb`.

How do I get these values in IronPython? Of course, I could loop over all rows and aggregate the result using a dictionary.  But I'd much rather use Spotfire's code to do the calculation. I'd prefer not to need the intermediate visualisation either, but just retrieve the calculated values directly.

TIBCO documentation shows there's a [`ColumnExpression`](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/api//html/T_Spotfire_Dxp_Data_Expressions_ColumnExpression.htm) class that could be used to represent the expressions. There is also the [`Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Calculations`](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/api//html/N_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Calculations.htm) namespace, but I can't find any mention of expressions there.

Comment: Do you think [this](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html//ncfe/ncfe_date_and_time_functions.htm) is of helpful?

Comment: I'm afraid not; those functions operate on dates, returning parts of them, whereas I'm looking for the aggregated values of other columns, based on those (parts of) dates.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm looking to that myself but I haven't found anything useful

Comment: @JoseDanielChacónBogarín no, I got nowhere with it. It's been a while since I worked on that project, but I think I worked around it with database views.